# Python pygame IndentationError

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pygame, indentation

So I just finished up with a good amount of learning python and working on learning pygame. So I am following along with this free online book, and the first thing of code in the book of making a window with hello world on the top is giving me an error:

Heres the code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
while True: # main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

pygame.display.update()
```

Heres the error:

```
  File "pygame.py", line 9
    if event.type == QUIT:
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This code works fine at my end. Are you sure all the identations are spaces or tabs?

Answer (score 1):

As presented, this code works fine at this end.  If you are still having a problem I suggest you look at tabs vs spaces in your editor.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Python is a space sensitive language. The compiler actually cares whether there is a mix of spaces and tabs throughout the program.

Stick to one of either kind throughout your code and this will resolve the issue.